# How to handle arithmetic operator < and > in antlr grammar that removes html tags

Tags: parsing, antlr3, context-free-grammar

Following is my antlr 3 grammar. I want to strip off content inside html tags.
The problem arises when I have arithmetic operator `< >` inside the tag.
How can this be handled?

```
grammar T;
options {
  output=AST;
}
tokens {
  ROOT;
}
parse
  :  text+  ;
text
  :  (tag)=> tag !
  | SPACE !
  |  outsidetag 
  ;
SPACE
    :    (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ ;
tag
  :  OPEN INSIDETAG  CLOSE  ;
CLOSE : '>' ;
OPEN  : '<' ;
INSIDETAG 
: ~(CLOSE|OPEN)+ ;
outsidetag
  :  ~(SPACE) ;
```

Comment: eg :sameha < var ( variable > value) >     i need to strip off evrything inside <> and output "sameha"

Comment: Can you be more specific about the allowed syntax? Those aren't HTML tags.

Comment: yes they arent html .basically they are free marker tags .there can be 2 possibilities :  1. either the arithmetic operators < and > wont be there inside tags <> (this case is simple and solved by the current grammar)                     2. or if they are present inside , then the arithmetic expression will be surrounded by curly braces () .... eg: < ( counter > threshold)||(counter < limit) >

Comment: I hav tried a lot but all in vain . please help

Answer (score 1):

First you don't need to check for OPEN in your INSIDETAG rule, since there is no harm in skipping it there. In fact you want it that way. Additionally combine tag and INSIDETAG and make it greedy so it tries to consume anything until the last CLOSE TOKEN, skipping so any intermediate ones:

```
tag: options { greedy = true; }: OPEN ~CLOSE* CLOSE;
```

Comment: If my comment solved your problem or got you in the right direction please accept it as answer.